# How to play one video from array at a time in ReactJS & AG Grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Getting response from API. API response

```
API response : 

    0:
    Camera_Number: "Camera_1"
    Company_Name: "Fraction Analytics Limited"
    Floor Number: "Ground_Floor"
    Group_Name: "Group_1"
    Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/0"
```

After populating data to table create one button then ag-grid look like this

[image]

I am currently mapping through all the videos to button and I click button it opens multiple video but I want only one video at a time.

app.js

```
const initialValue = { Name: "", Floor: "", Group: "", Camera: "", Videos: "" };

export default function App(data, handleFormSubmit) {
  const { id } = data;
  const actionButton = (params) => {
    setResponse(params.response);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const [response, setResponse] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setFormData(initialValue);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { value, id } = e.target;
    // console.log(value,id)
    setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value });
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Name", field: "Company_Name", filter: "agSetColumnFilter" },
    { headerName: "Floor", field: "Floor Number" },
    { headerName: "Group", field: "Group_Name" },
    { headerName: "Camera", field: "Camera_Number" },
    { headerName: "Videos", field: "Video_Name" },
    {
      headerName: "Actions",
      field: "Video_Name",
      cellRendererFramework: (params) => (
        <div>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="medium"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => actionButton(params)}
          >
            Play
          </Button>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    console.log("grid is ready");
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/get_all")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.results);
        setResponse(resp.results);
        params.api.applyTransaction({ add: resp.results });
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center"> React FastAPI Integration</h1>
      <h3> API Data </h3>
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "400px" }}>
      </div>
      <div>
          <DialogContent>
            <iframe width="420" height="315" title="videos" src={id} />
          </DialogContent>
          ;
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary" variant="outlined">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => handleFormSubmit()}
              variant="contained"
            >
              {id ? "Update" : "Download"}
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Multiple video open at same time,I don't know how to properly play one at a time. I appreciate any help. I've been stuck on this for a few days.

Multiple video open at a time. but i want one video at a time

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the click handler of the button. You cannot get row data with that.

Add a `colId` to column definition for actions. Then handle the `onCellClicked` action of the grid. You can get the row data using `params.node.data`.

```
const [videoName, setVideoName] = useState("");

function onCellClicked(params) {
    // maps to colId: "action" in columnDefs,
    if (params.column.colId === "action") {
      // set videoName for the row
      setVideoName(params.node.data.Video_Name);
      setOpen(true);
    }
}

// grid config
<AgGridReact
  ...
  rowData={response}
  onCellClicked={onCellClicked}>
</AgGridReact>

// access videoName in dialog content
<DialogContent>
 {/* <iframe width="420" height="315" title="videos" src={id} /> */}
 <div>{videoName}</div>
</DialogContent>
```

[image: Edit reverent-zhukovsky-gt4mln]

**Output** - Click on any row's play button. Result is that rows video url. You can now use this to play the actual video.

[image: Output]

Comment: @Raghav Can you post the complete app.js including the imports.

Comment: Could you please share one data object of api response.

Comment: @Raghav Answer updated with output & sandbox link.

Comment: @AseemGautam If possible could you please help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496250/data-disappears-in-the-react-hooks-page-after-iterating-and-setting-to-the-stat

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood the question, it is because in `DialogContent` you are mapping through *all* `response`, and showing all of them.
Instead why not here:

```
const actionButton = (params) => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
```

instead of storing `true`, store `id` (it seems video name could work in your case too) of the row clicked.
Then inside `DialogContent` render only one `iframe`, with video based on that `id`.

PS. You can pass `!!id` as `open` prop to Dialog, which means if there is something in `id`, the Dialog will open (assuming there are no ids with falsy values).

---

Or you can actually store the whole row itself in state, and then you can more easily access it, here is simple example what I mean:

```
let data = [
  { name: 'david', id: 0 },
  { name: 'nick', id: 1 },
  { name: 'john', id: 2 },
];

export default function App() {
  let [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((x) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={x.id}
            onClick={() => {
              setClicked(x);
            }}
          >
            Row {x.name}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div>Clicked row {clicked && clicked.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Raghav I am not familiar with that grid but here `onClick={() => actionButton(params)}
` there should be a way to pass `id` (or some info identifying which row was clicked) instead of `params`. Then store it in state. Then just find a video based on that `id` inside `DialogContent`.