# Data disappears in the react-hooks page, after iterating and setting to the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am getting all records from db, for those records which has the status `Yes` I am trying to set the button label to `Save` as per line `41 to 48`  in CSB. But due to some reason data disappears in the react-hooks page, after iterating and setting the `` setProcessRequest("Save")`; ``. Could someone please advise me what could be the issue here, I have added CSB link below for reference.

Please note: CSB link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-fog-0lwpi0?file=/src/App.js

```
  const data = [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "Test1",
        email: "test@test.com",
        processRequest: "Accept",
        status: "Yes"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Del",
        email: "del@test.com",
        processRequest: "Accept",
        status: "No"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Troi",
        email: "troi@test.com",
        processRequest: "Accept",
        status: "Yes"
      }
    ];
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
              try {
                //const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/requestlist');
                setRequestList(data);
                setRequestList(
                   requestList.map((item) => {
                      if (item.status === "Yes") {
                         setProcessRequest("Save");
                       }
                      return item;
                    })
                  );
              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
              }
            };
            fetchData();
          }, []);

return (
    <section className="col1">
      <h3>Players Requests</h3>
      {requestList.map(({ id, name, email, processRequest }) => (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="playerRow">
            <label key={id}>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="plyName">
                  <span>{name}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="plyEmail">
                  <span>{email}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="btnStyle4">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={(e) => processRequestData(id, email)}
                  >
                    {processRequest}
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className="btnStyle4">
                  <input type="button" value="Decline Request"></input>
                </div>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to use previous state to update, change below code to make it work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        //const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/requestlist');
        setRequestList(data);

        setRequestList((pre) => // ⬅ use previous state here to update 
          pre.map((item) => {
            if (item.status === "Yes") {
              setProcessRequest("Save");
            }
            return item;
          })
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

#### Explanation:

Both `setRequestList` is called on mount, ie. right after the first render, and at that perticular render phase, both are pointing to the empty array, first you called the `setRequestList(data);`, but notice the state does not update immediately, therefore, calling the next setState is essentially doing the following:

```
setRequestList([].map( () => {} )) // mapping over an empty array
```

You are overriding the first `setRequestList(data);`, and it returns an empty array. This is because setting state does not update state immediately, it saves it to the next render phase, untill then, it stays the same, ie. empty array. But `setRequestList( (prev) => {} )` will give you the result of previous pending state, and calculate next state based on it.

See more at [React state as a snapshot](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-as-a-snapshot), and it has a [good example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sandpack-project-forked-6fwr8i?file=/App.js) of replicate your situation

Comment: I have tried your answer, and used ``pre`` state as advised but still it is not updating to Save

Comment: Use [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-night-vuv1od?file=/src/App.js) you can see console.log(processRequest) result is `save`

Comment: Yes, i saw that but unfortunately it is not setting the button label to ``Save``  here ``<button type="button" onClick={(e) => processRequestData(id, email)}>{processRequest}</button>``

Comment: Initially the button will have ``Accept`` label for the record, but as soon the admin user click on the Accept button it will send a post request and it will save ``Yes`` to status column. So while getting all records from database, those records having status set to Yes will display the button label as ``Save`` and records doesn't have Yes status or blank still will display Accept label.

Comment: I have added the screenshot for some reference

Comment: Hi, I found out that you are overrding `processRequest` variable. First you define it in a state, then overriding it in `requestList.map(({ id, name, email, processRequest }) => ()} `, so that's why your state `const [processRequest, setProcessRequest] = useState("Accept");` doesn't do anything, if you wish to update the accept button, you can use filter function to do so

Comment: So, I guess [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-feather-j5nfe4) is what you want to do eventually, let me know if there's any confusion left.

Comment: Thank you Enfield, my doubt is if the ``status === Yes````, then why the button is not changing the label to ``Save `` 
For`` status === No``, the button can still display as Accept.

Comment: Where should i correct now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245319/discussion-between-soccerway-and-enfield-li).

Comment: Can you join the chat? we can continue there, take a look at this [final version](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-feather-j5nfe4?file=/src/App.js)