# useState hook - passing in callback vs state value

Tags: reactjs

In this very simple click counter example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{count}</button>
}
```

My understanding of the flow is:

1. Component gets mounted with `count`=0
2. When button is clicked, new `count` state is set with increment of 1.
3. That triggers a re-render, so now I have `count`=1, and repeats.

---

However, using the same understanding, why does it not work here?

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1)
    }, 500)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  console.log(count) // this stops at 1, so the timer stops triggering??
  return <h1>{count}</h1> // get stuck at 1
}
```

The outcome of the above code is that the `count` gets stuck at value 1. (and weirdly the console.log stops too).

I thought each time the setInterval timer triggers, the count increment will cause a re-render with **new** `count` value and therefore it will just increase by 1 forever?

The fix here is to simply pass in a function argument to access `prevState`:

```
const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1)
    }, 500)
```

But why couldn't the first approach work?
Hope someone can point me to a good article or documentation of this, I tried searching around but couldn't get any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach doesn't work because with this

```
setCount(count + 1)
```

You are creating a copy of the *count* value at that particular time you created the callback. This means that every 500ms you will re-execute this line

```
setCount(0 + 1)
```

That won't cause a re-render because react is intelligent enough to understand that you are passing the same value to the setCount function so the re-render would not be necessary.

However by passing a callback to *setCount*:

```
setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1)
```

You are saying that you want the current value of the state *count*, so each time the argument of that function will be different and therefore it will cause a re-render.

You can find a doc about this topic here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: ah that's it!! thank you! So that's basically the same idea if I do `useCallback` on the `handleClick` function.

Comment: @Hakim Could you please help me with this question if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72496250/data-disappears-in-the-react-hooks-page-after-iterating-and-setting-to-the-stat